# What can I do with the results of EXEC (sql) AT LinkedServer?

Tags: sql-server

I am using the EXEC (sql) AT LinkedServer command to get some data from a remote server. So far the only thing I can do with the results in my script is insert them into a local table.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable (Col1 VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #MyTable
EXEC ('SELECT Col1 FROM MyDB.dbo.Table1 WHERE Col2 = ?', 'Val2') AT REMOTEDDB
```

This works great and I can use this.

I wanted to join the result set to a local table directly like OPENQUERY does but I can't find syntax for that. It may not be supported. I can't use OPENQUERY because the data is too big and I need to apply run time parameters.

Are there any other options for processing and working with the results of the EXEC AT command that don't require inserting it into a table first?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, that I know of, to join directly to an Exec.  Inserting into a temp table would be your best bet in my opinion.  Even if you joined directly in syntax the same thing would still happen, SQL Server needs to pull the remote data local and then perform the join.

Another option might be to pass a table parameter and have that output.  You can do that with sp_executesql.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would sync that table locally using something like sql agent every 5 minutes or so. Then I do the join to that local table.

In my experience, querying remote table using link server never gives me the best query plan available. I would avoid that if I can.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in caching remote results locally before using them. On average, this approach gives the best performance.

Also, you can try a static query:

```
select *
from dbo.LocalTable lt
  inner join RemoteDB.MyDB.dbo.Table1 rt on lt.Id = rt.Id
where rt.Col2 = 'Val2';
```

If it wouldn't work straight away, at least you can try REMOTE join hint. Of course, normally it should be a last resort (the hint, I mean).